# PHP array_filter: if array doesn't have my value return array without changes

Tags: php, array-filter

To filter an array by key value I do this

```
//$Myitems this is an array
$make = '3';
$MyfilterMain = array_filter($Myitems, function($Myitems) use($make) {
    $extra_fields_decode = json_decode($Myitems['extra_fields'], true);
    $main_value = $extra_fields_decode['1']['value'];
    return $main_value == $make;
})
```

Everything works correctly. But I want to make a condition: if my key value ($make) is not in the array, so that the array is returned without filtering. To return the original array $Myitems. Because next I want to do other things with it. I want to apply array_slice. Exemple:

```
$FirstItem = array_slice($Myitems, 0, 1);
```

To begin with, I tried to simply return the original array back like this. But it doesn't work.

```
$MyfilterMain = array_filter($Myitems, function($Myitems) use($make) {
    $extra_fields_decode = json_decode($Myitems['extra_fields'], true);
    $main_value = $extra_fields_decode['1']['value'];
    if ($main_value) {
        return $main_value == $make;
    } else {
        return $Myitems;
    }
})
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: It's always good to follow the [naming conventions](https://namingconvention.org/php/) for variables: https://namingconvention.org/php/variable-naming.html

Comment: This is great. I'll take it on board. But that doesn't solve my problem now.

Comment: Another piece of advice: Don't use the same variable name for the array and the callback function parameter. It's confusing when you reuse variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this in the `array_filter()` callback. If `$make` is not in the array, the result of the filter will be an empty array. Check for that and use the original array instead.

```
$MyfilterMain = array_filter($Myitems, function($Myitems) use($make) {
    $extra_fields_decode = json_decode($Myitems['extra_fields'], true);
    $main_value = $extra_fields_decode['1']['value'];
    return $main_value == $make;
});
if (count($MyfilterMain) == 0) {
    $MyfilterMain = $Myitems;
}
```

Comment: You are genios. Your code doesn't work, but it gave me an idea. And I did this: ```$MyFilterNext = $MyfilterMain ? $MyfilterMain : $Myitems;``` and everything worked as it should. Soon I will finalize the code with all the conditions and add it here.

Comment: I got the capitalization of the variable wrong. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

An answer marked as correct is correct. But I decided to do a little on my own. That also works well.

```
$MyfilterMain = array_filter($Myitems, function($Myitems) use($make) {
    $extra_fields_decode = json_decode($Myitems['extra_fields'], true);
    $main_value = $extra_fields_decode['0']['value'];
        return $main_value == $make;
});
$MyFilterMainNext = $MyfilterMain ? $MyfilterMain : $Myitems;
```

In the template

```
<?php foreach($MyFilterMainNext as $mylist) : ?>
// Your data
<?php endforeach; ?>
```